# 'Error 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint' al ejecutar el comando 'php artisan migrate' en Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Estoy intentando crear las migraciones para una app que estoy haciendo en Laravel y al ejecutar el comando `php artisan migrate` o `php artisan migrate:fresh` obtengo el siguiente error:

**SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint (SQL: alter table `users` add constraint `users_role_id_foreign` foreign key (`role_id`) references `roles` (`id`) on delete cascade on update cascade)**

Las migraciones que tengo ahora mismo son:

**create_users_table**

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->integer('role_id')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->integer('profile_id')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('role_id')->references('id')->on('roles')
                ->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
            $table->foreign('profile_id')->references('id')->on('profiles')
                ->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
        });
    }
```

Dentro de esta tabla es donde tengo las dos claves foráneas que supongo que me están dando el error

**create_profiles_table**

```
  public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('profiles', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('phone', 9);
            $table->string('city');
            $table->string('province');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

**create_roles_table**

```
 public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('roles', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('nombre');
            $table->string('description');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Ya he intentado cambiar el orden de las migraciones y no creo que ese sea el problema, pero aquí dejo una captura:
[image: Orden migraciones]

A ver si alguien puede echarme una mano ya que no es la primera vez que me sale este error y no termino de saber cuál es el problema ni como solucionarlo.

Gracias de antemano,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Estas declarando mal tus datos en tu migracion cambia

```
$table->integer('role_id')->unsigned()->index();
```

por:

```
$table->unsignedBigInteger('role_id');
```

y haz lo mismo con el campo `profile_id`

Como declaras tus campos fue descartada si no me equivoco desde laravel 6, para mas informacion acerca de los cambios en cada version te sugiero revisar la documentacion

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/

y para declarar llaves foraneas

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/migrations#foreign-key-constraints

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, ya he podido solucionarlo, llevaba ya más de 1 año sin realizar ningún proyecto con Laravel y no estaba al tanto de los cambios.